# Is it possible to pass object as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var obj = {
  name1: 1,
  name2: 2
}

function myF(obj) {
  console.log(obj.name1) // by idea it must return 1
};
myF(obj)
```

Does anybody know how to pass object in function?

Comment: Have you tried it? Other than the spelling error that should work...

Comment: Anything that can be assigned to a variable can also be passed to a function. You could have at least just run the code and see for yourself. Not sure I see the point of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes objects make great parameters.

```
var p1 = {
    name: "Tom",
    age: 23,
    isMale: true
};
var p2 = {
    name: "Alicia",
    age: 21,
    isMale: false
};
var p3 = {
    name: "Landon",
    age: 1,
    isMale: true
};


function greeting(person) {
    var str = '';
    str += 'Hello my name is ';
    str += person.name + ' '; 
    str += 'I'm a ' + person.age + ' year old ';
    if (person.isMale) {
        str += age > 18 ? 'man' : 'boy';
    } else {
        str += age > 18 ? 'woman' : 'girl';
    }
    if (person.age < 3) {
        str = 'Bah'
    }
    console.log(str);
};

greeting(p1); // 'Hello my name is Tom I'm a 23 year old man';
greeting(p2); // 'Hello my name is Alicia I'm a 21 year old woman;
greeting(p3); // 'Bah';
```

Objects are good for when you have a grouping of values that belong together and you don't want to pass them in individually (If they belong together they rarely should be passed on their own.)

Answer (score 0):

This is very common practice. Many libraries will utilize a `config` object so one does not have to specify multiple params

Example:

```
function makeSquare(height, width, color, border)
```

Could be easier represented with

```
function makeSquare(config)
```

This would make it easier for users to leave out some parameters, say you wanted to makeSquare without a border you would not need to include the border param if you are passing and object.

With parameters

```
makeSquare(10, 20, red, null)
```

with Obj

```
config = {
  height: 10,
  width: 10,
  color: 'red'
};

makeSquare(config);
```

If you had an extensive amount of configuration options you could see where this may save quite a bit of development time and space